# Remap dictionary with new dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to replace dictionary keys as well as values with the new dictionary in Python.

For instance:

```
dic1 = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4}
dic2 = {'A': ['B', 'C', 'D','K'], 'C': ['C', 'D', 'A', 'F'], 'D': ['A', 'B', 'C'] }
```

In Dic2 I have 'K' and 'F' values that are not present in dic1. I want to remove them as well.
I want output in the following form:

```
out_dic = {1: [2, 3, 4], 3: [3, 4, 1], 4: [1, 2, 3]}
```

I have found a solution that is not fast enough. First I replace the values of the dictionary with new values. Then update the keys with new keys.

Comment: If you `dict` has this specific structure the you can try `ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r"'([A-Z]+)'", lambda x: str(dic1.get(x.group(1))), str(dic2)))` . Don;t forget to `import re` and `import ast`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dic1` serves as a mapping of values according to which you want to replace all values in `dic2`. So just iterate on all items of `dic2` and use the mapping to replace them:

```py
dic3 = {}
for key, values in dic2.items():
    dic3[dic1[key]] = [dic1[value] for value in values]

print(dic3)
```

If you have values in `dic2` that might not be present in `dic1`, change to this to leave them as they were in `dic2`:

```
    dic3[dic1.get(key, key)] = [dic1.get(value, value) for value in values]
```

And if you want to completely remove them, use:

```py
for key, values in dic2.items():
    if key in dic1:
        dic3[dic1[key]] = [dic1[value] for value in values if value in dic1]
```

Which gives:

```
{1: [2, 3, 4], 3: [3, 4, 1], 4: [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. But there is problem with my dictionary as I have some values in ```dic2``` which are not present in ```dic1```. Which through an error. how to avoid that. If element is not in dic1 then remove it from dic2

Answer (score 0):

```
new = {
    v: [dic1[v2] for v2 in dic2[k] if v2 in dic1]
        for k, v in dic1.items() if k in dic2
}
```

Comment: please add some textual context to your code. This would increase your answer quality a lot.

Comment: It makes a dict comprehension and list comprehesion at the same time. Sorry but English is not my language.